# What does input[[...]] do in a shiny observe event?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, observers

In the below code, I'm trying to understand what the `input[[...]]` in the two commented `observeEvent()` functions do. Could someone please explain?

I'm trying to adapt this code so the function of the individual delete action buttons rendered under each added table can be consolidated into a single `selectInput()` or `selectizeInput()` box, showing all tables available for deletion, and then I can remove these individual table delete buttons. I need to understand this `input[[...]]` part in the below code first, so perhaps I can do the equivalent with `selectInput()` or `selectizeInput()`. I've only used `input$...` before in referring to action buttons or other user input widgets for an `observeEvent()`.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

data1 <- data.frame(row.names = c("A","B","C","Sum"),"Col 1"=c(1,1,0,2),check.names=FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  actionButton("addTbl","Add table"),
  br(),br(),
  tags$div(id = "placeholder",        
           tags$div(
             style = "display: inline-block", 
             rHandsontableOutput("hottable1")
           )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  uiTbl <- reactiveValues(div_01_tbl = data1) # mod
  rv <- reactiveValues()                
  
  observeEvent(input$hottable1, {uiTbl$div_01_tbl <- hot_to_r(input$hottable1)}) # mod
  
  output$hottable1 <- renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(uiTbl$div_01_tbl, useTypes = TRUE)}) # mod
  
  observeEvent(input$addTbl, {
    divID <- paste0("div_", if(input$addTbl+1 < 10){"0"},input$addTbl+1) # mod
    dtID <- paste0(divID, "_DT")
    btnID <- paste0(divID, "_rmv")
    uiTbl[[paste0(divID,"_tbl")]] <- data1 # captures initial dataframe values
    
    insertUI(
      selector = "#placeholder",
      ui = tags$div(
        id = divID,
        style = "display:inline-block;",
        rHandsontableOutput(dtID), 
        actionButton(btnID, "Delete", class = "pull-left btn btn-danger"),
      )
    )
    
    output[[dtID]] <- renderRHandsontable({
      req(uiTbl[[paste0(divID,"_tbl")]])
      rhandsontable(uiTbl[[paste0(divID,"_tbl")]], useTypes = TRUE)
    })
    
    # print(btnID)
    
    # what does input[[dtID]] below do?
    observeEvent(input[[dtID]], {uiTbl[[paste0(divID,"_tbl")]] <- hot_to_r(input[[dtID]])})
    
    # what does input[[btnID]] below do?
    observeEvent(input[[btnID]],{
      removeUI(selector = paste0("#", divID))
      rv[[divID]] <- NULL
      uiTbl[[paste0(divID,"_tbl")]] <- NULL
    },
    ignoreInit = TRUE,
    once = TRUE
    )
  })
  
  
  observe({
    tables_list <- reactiveValuesToList(uiTbl)
    tables_list <- tables_list[order(names(tables_list))]
    table_lengths <- lengths(tables_list)
    cumsum_table_lengths <- cumsum(table_lengths)[table_lengths != 0L]
    
    for(i in seq_along(cumsum_table_lengths)){
      names(uiTbl[[names(cumsum_table_lengths[i])]]) <- paste("Col", cumsum_table_lengths[i])
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You created `dtID` as an object `dtID <- paste0(divID, "_DT")`, thus to evaluate the value, you need `[[`, instead of `$` as `$` does literal evaluation i.e. checking if there is `dtID` instead of the value from it

Comment: It is similar to extracting columns from the input data i.e. `v1 <- "Col 1";
> data1$v1#
NULL` whereas `data1[[v1]]#
[1] 1 1 0 2` or `data1$"Col 1"
[1] 1 1 0 2`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/3358272 (comparison of `[` and `[[` and `$`).

Comment: `input[[dtID]]` and `input[[btnID]]` are passed as `observeEvent`'s `eventExpr`. Accordingly `observeEvent` is triggered to run after those inputs changed.